# Django app missing after import?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a django project using win7 with aptana3/pydev . I have a project called mytest and I'm trying to import an app called 'django-mailbox' into my project (http://django-mailbox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/installation.html)

Following the directions I performed:

```
~tools/virtualenvs/mytest
$ pip install django-mailbox
Downloading/unpacking django-mailbox
  Downloading django-mailbox-3.0.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-mailbox    

Downloading/unpacking six (from django-mailbox)
  Downloading six-1.4.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package six    

Installing collected packages: django-mailbox, six
  Running setup.py install for django-mailbox    

  Running setup.py install for six    

Successfully installed django-mailbox six
Cleaning up...
```

I have also added:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_mailbox',
```

to my settings.py file.

I was expecting to see the 'django_mailbox' directory within the 'mytest' dirctory, but its not. What happened, and where is it?

edit:

My directory structure is:

```
|-development
|---projects
|---tools
|-----PortableGit
|-----Portablepython - ( actually installed in here ) ( Global files ? )
|-----Virtalenvs
|--------mytest   ( I thought it should be installed here )
|--------otherfile

  /development/tools/virtualenvs/mytest
 $ find ./ -type d | sed -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g;s/--/ |-/'
  |-
  |-mytest
  |-chat1
  |-Lib
  |---encodings
  |---site-packages
  |-----setuptools
  |-------command
  |-------tests
  |-------_backport
  |---------hashlib
  |-----_markerlib
  |-----setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg-info
  |-----pip
  |-------backwardcompat
  |-------commands
  |-------vcs
  |-------vendor
  |---------distlib
  |-----------_backport
  |---------html5lib
  |-----------filters
  |-----------serializer
  |-----------treebuilders
  |-----------treewalkers
  |-----------trie
  |-----pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info
  |---distutils
  |-Include
  |---pygame
  |---pycairo
  |---pygtk-2.0
  |-----pygtk
  |-Scripts
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `virtualenv`, it is stored very similar to the Python installation of the  packages.

```
<path_to_virtualenv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to python and django. I'm still not seeing it. As far as <path_to_virtualenv> do you mean ~tools/virtualenvs/mytest ( mytest is the project name) ?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean.

Comment: I eventually figured out that the path was: ~tools\portablepython\app\lib\site-packages . I suspect ( based on http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290325/python-virtualenv-quickstart-django ) that this occured because when I set up my project in virtualenv, I did not use the --no-site-packages flag, and consequently ( according to the article ) my project symlinks to the global site packages in my local environment. Does this make sense?

Comment: Actually, That post you are refering to is really old, and `--no-site-packages` is on by default in the new versions of virtualenv. By default, the libraries are stored in the site-packages directory specific to your virtualenv. That is what I mentioned in the answer. Please refer the documentation for more details

Comment: Just to be clear, I have updated the question with the directory structure and indicated where the files are installed. Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by <path_to_virtualenv> because if you mean ~tools/virtualenvs/mytest, there actually is no /lib/python2.7/site-packages/ subdirectory in there. I've included that directory file structure as well